# Loop, random number generator, then checker

Tags: java

trying to further my comprehension of loops and I found some questions online that I'm trying to complete but I got stuck on the second last one.

The original question was :

loop4(int val). This method uses a loop (for or while?) to do the following. Generate a random number between 1 and 10 (including 1 and 10) 10 times and count how many times val is generated, then print that number out.

What I've managed to do so far:

```
public int Loop4(int val){
    for(int i = Math.random()*10; i<= 10; val!=0){
        if (i == val) {
            System.out.println(//I cannot for the life of me think of how I could constantly increment a +1 to this value because I only want to end up with 1 number in the end)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which part are you stuck in ?

Comment: Hint: you'll want to print OUTSIDE the loop.  You'll need a counter variable.

Comment: val!=0 - What does that do?

Comment: Do your homeworks! http://www.cs.montana.edu/~sean.yaw/Teaching/Fall2014/111/Outlabs/Outlab4/Outlab4

Comment: @FedericoPonzi too bad the homework tag was deprecated ;). This is also why I tried to explain some things instead of just giving the answer

Answer (score 1):

This code will do the trick:)

```
public int Loop4(int val){

        int totalCount = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<= 10; i++){
           int generatedNumber = (int)(Math.random()*10);
           if (generatedNumber  == val){
             totalCount++;
           }
         }

         System.out.print(totalCount  );

}
```

Comment: This will not compile make sure to cast Math.random() * 10 to (int).

Answer (score 1):

Simply create an count value and increment it.

```
public int Loop4(int val){
   int count = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++){
     if ((int)(Math.random()*10) == val) {
        count++;
     }
   }
   System.out.println(count);
   return count;
}
```

Comment: This won't work make sure to cast Math.random() * 10 to (int).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like this.  From your question you only want to loop 10 times and count how many times val is generated.  You should create a total variable and increment each time the new random number == val.

Ex:

```
public int Loop4(int val){
    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
        if ((int)(Math.random()*10) == val) {
            total++;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things in your code that you need to consider.

First, `Math.random()` returns a `double`, not an `int` so you have to cast it: `(int) Math.random()` (However casting this will cause some issue with rounding so do some research on that).

Second, the third argument in a `for` loop needs to be an iteration, not a comparison. 
Ex: `i++`, `++i`, `--i`

Third, create another variable `int count = 0` that will count the number of times a number appears and place: `count++` inside of your inner `if` statement and then have the `System.out` print it after your iteration.

Comment: I no Math.random returns a double but I only want an integer, so unless I"m mistaken it will always round down to an integer value which is what I'm trying to achieve.  I do not want a double.

Comment: Yes it will always round down. So all you need to do is cast it if that is the desired effect